# Lodash debounce not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, debouncing

it would be best to first look at my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Services from 'Services'; // Webservice calls

export default class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value || null
    }
  }

  onChange(value) {
    this.setState({ value });

    // This doesn't call Services.setValue at all
    _.debounce(() => Services.setValue(value), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          onChange={(event, value) => this.onChange(value)}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Just a simple input. In the contructor it grabs `value` from the props (if available) at sets a local state for the component.

Then in the `onChange` function of the `input` I update the state and then try to call the webservice endpoint to set the new value with `Services.setValue()`.

What does work is if I set the `debounce` directly by the `onChange` of the input like so:

```
<input 
  value={this.state.value} 
  onChange={_.debounce((event, value) => this.onChange(value), 1000)} 
/>
```

But then `this.setState` gets called only every 1000 milliseconds and update the view. So typing in a textfield ends up looking weird since what you typed only shows a second later.

What do I do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem occurs because you aren't calling the debounce function, you could do in the following manner

```
export default class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value || null
    }
    this.servicesValue = _.debounce(this.servicesValue, 1000);
  }

  onChange(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.servicesValue(value);
  }
  servicesValue = (value) => {
      Services.setValue(value)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          onChange={(event, value) => this.onChange(value)}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! I could also just wrap _.debounce(...) in a self executing anonymous function in `onChange` correct?

Comment: yes, you could do that too, however, in that case you would be returning a new debounced function everytime, So the above approach is better than what you suggest

Answer (score 49):

Solution for those who came here because throttle / debounce doesn't work  with `FunctionComponent` - you need to store debounced function via [useRef()](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables):

```
export const ComponentName = (value = null) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);

  const setServicesValue = value => Services.setValue(value);

  const setServicesValueDebounced = useRef(_.debounce(setServicesValue, 1000));

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: { value } }) => {
    setInputValue(value);
    setServicesValueDebounced.current(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />;
};
```

[This medium article](https://rajeshnaroth.medium.com/using-throttle-and-debounce-in-a-react-function-component-5489fc3461b3) perfectly explains what happens:

> Local variables inside a function expires after every call. Every time
> the component is re-evaluated, the local variables gets initialized
> again. Throttle and debounce works using `window.setTimeout()` behind
> the scenes. Every time the function component is evaluated, you are
> registering a fresh `setTimeout` callback.
> So we will use `useRef()` hook as value returned by `useRef()` does not get re-evaluated every time the functional component is executed. The only inconvenience is that you have to access your stored value via the `.current` property.

I've created [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lodash-throttle?file=src%2FApp.js) with tiny `lodash.throttle` and `lodash.debounce` packages so you can experiment with both and choose suitable behavior

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've got a functional component with a controlled input that updates the state and also sets a value via a service, and your sandbox really nails it. That said, I find useCallback to be an even better fit, as indicated in an update to that Medium article.

Answer (score 19):

For a React functional component, debounce does not work by default. You will have to do the following for it to work:

```
const debouncedFunction= React.useCallback(debounce(functionToCall, 400), []);
```

useCallback makes use of the function returned by debounce and works as expected.
Although, this is a bit more complicated when you want to use state variables inside the debounced function (Which is usually the case).

```
React.useCallback(debounce(fn, timeInMs), [])
```

The second argument for React.useCallback is for dependencies. If you would like to use a state or prop variable in the debounced function, by default, it uses an an old version of the state variable which will cause your function to use the historical value of the variable which is not what you need.
To solve this issue, you will have to include the state variable like you do in React.useEffect like this:

```
React.useCallback(debounce(fn, timeInMs), [stateVariable1, stateVariable2])
```

This implementation might solve your purpose. But you will notice that the debounced function is called every time the state variables (stateVariable1, stateVariable2) passed as dependencies change. Which might not be what you need especially if using a controlled component like an input field.

The best solution I realized is to put some time to change the functional component to a class based component and use the following implementation:

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super();
        this.state = {...};
        this.functionToCall= debounce(this.functionToCall.bind(this), 400, {'leading': true});
    }
```

Comment: thanks, @SummerFort
```
useCallback(debounce(fn, timeInMs), [])
```
is what I needed!

Comment: great to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a hook for those who are using react functional components.

> It's typescript, but you can ignore type annotations to use on your javascript application.

### | use-debounce.ts |

```
import { debounce, DebounceSettings } from 'lodash'
import { useRef } from 'react'

interface DebouncedArgs<T> {
  delay?: number
  callback?: (value: T) => void
  debounceSettings?: DebounceSettings
}



export const useDebounce = <T = unknown>({ callback, debounceSettings, delay = 700 }: DebouncedArgs<T>) => {
  const dispatchValue = (value: T) => callback?.(value)

  const setValueDebounced = useRef(debounce(dispatchValue, delay, { ...debounceSettings, maxWait: debounceSettings?.maxWait || 1400 }))

  return (value: T) => setValueDebounced.current(value)
}
```

### | usage: |

```
export const MyInput: FC = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')
  const debounce = useDebounce({ callback: onChange })

  const handleOnInput = (evt: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = evt.currentTarget
    setValue(value)
    debounce(value)
  }

  function onChange(value: string) {
    // send request to the server for example
    console.log(value)
  }

  return <input value={value} onInput={handleOnInput} />
}
```

Comment: Tip for those needing to set a state from the callback, pass the set function as an argument. Clean and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for functional component - use useCallback

```
export const ComponentName = (value = null) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);

  const setServicesValue = value => Services.setValue(value);

  const setServicesValueDebounced = useCallback(_.debounce(setServicesValue, 500), []);

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: { value } }) => {
    setInputValue(value);
    setServicesValueDebounced(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} />;
};
```

Comment: if `useCallback` dependency is empty you can make it normal function

Comment: `useCallback` was already covered in [an established answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859849/450127). Does yours add anything new to that? If so, can you please describe the differences in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Lodash debounce solution for Class based components

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

class MyComponent extends Component {

  mySearchFunction = (keyword) => {
    /* API Call or something else
      searchApi(keyword)
    */
  }

  searchWithDebounce = debounce(this.mySearchFunction, 1000)

  render () {
    return (<div>
      <input onChange={ e => this.searchWithDebounce(e.target.value) } />
    </div>)
  }

export default MyComponent
```